# Can every top down memoization algorithms be implemented in a bottom up tabulation approach?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I been looking at [this post](https://programming.guide/dynamic-programming-vs-memoization-vs-tabulation.html) about various ways to optimize a Fibonacci function.

Both top down memoization and a bottom up tabulation solve the problem. And I believe both approaches are considered dynamic programming? (please correct me if I am wrong)
But it seems like the bottom up tabulation approach has better space complexity i.e. `o(1)`

My question is that, is it true that every problem that can be solved with top down memoization can also be solved with bottom up tabulation approach with better space complexity?

Comment: It's hard to answer universal questions, especially when it's not 100% precise what these terms mean. I would say computing catalan numbers using C[n+1] = sum(C[i]C[n-i], i=0..n) is a counter-example because the obvious bottom-up tabulation method does not have better space complexity as both are Theta(n). But you can "solve" the problem using a different approach with better space complexity.

Comment: How is that Fibonacci function in the link O(1) space? I agree with Paul that precise definitions are necessary here. But, in general, bottom-up DP is just a topological sort of the subproblem dependency DAG. Top-down DP is a depth-first search of that DAG. It is often, but certainly not always, possible to use your knowledge of the topological ordering to save space when doing bottom-up DP.

Comment: @kcsquared yea my bad the bottom up example in the link is not o(1) for space. It could be o(1) space but not sure why the author didn't mention it. Is the DAG the recursion tree here?